# How can you create a collection based on multiple IEnumerables

Tags: c#, generics

A class I want to operate on provides getters of type `IEnumerable<X>` and `IEnumerable<Y>` where X & Y are subclasses of base type T. I want to iterate over the contents of both treating them as type T. Is there a handy way to concatenate both into something which can be seen as `IEnumerable<T>`?

Example:

```
        IEnumerable<HeaderPart> headers = templateFile.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts;
        IEnumerable<FooterPart> footers = templateFile.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts;
        List<OpenXmlPart> result = new List<OpenXmlPart>();
        result.Concat<OpenXmlPart>(footers);
```

HeaderPart and FooterPart are both subclasses of OpenXmlPart but the 3rd line fails:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'Concat' and the best extension method
>   overload
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Note, I can't change either of the source data, I need to create a new collection - actually I want to do a `foreach` over it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Cast function to convert `IEnumerable<X>` to `IEnumerable<T>` and then `Concat` to append the second series

Something like:

```
listB.Cast<A>().Concat(listC.Cast<A>())
```

Answer (score 3):

In C#/.NET 4 or newer you can use [`Enumerable.Concat<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<T> result = xs.Concat<T>(ys);
```

For your specific case you can use [`List.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
List<OpenXmlPart> result = new List<OpenXmlPart>();
result.AddRange(headers.Cast<OpenXmlPart>());
result.AddRange(footers.Cast<OpenXmlPart>());
```

Comment: None of the types I try have a Concat method... What Enumerable have you got in mind?

Comment: I got my comments messed up, modified.

Comment: @John: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: 3.5, I added Linq and still getting all kinds of problems.

Comment: @Mark: Your code relies on the co-/contra-variance changes introduced in .NET 4. For .NET 3.5 you'd need to do `xs.Cast<T>().Concat(ys.Cast<T>())` instead.

Comment: @LukeH: +1 Oops... thanks! I was running in new Visual Studio and didn't consider this issue... Oh well, maybe I should leave this anyway since some people do use .NET 4.

Comment: Cool, it seems to be working after casting... I didn't know you could safely cast a collection like that. Now - is there a LINQ query way of doing this, i.e comparable to `SELECT OpenXMLPart part from headers, footers` or is LINQ not quite that advanced?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested, and don't know about readymade functionality for it, but instead of allocating new storage and moving data about, you **should** be able implement your own `EnumeratorBinder<T, X, Y>` template class, binding the two `IEnumerable` instances in the constructor, and [implement](http://www.manning-source.com/books/skeet/Chapter6sample.pdf) something on the lines of

```
IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerable()
{
  foreach ( X x in _enumX )
    yield return x;
  foreach ( Y y in _enumY )
    yield return y;
}
```

with suitable template constraints...

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what LINQ's `Concat` method does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx

Comment: Ah - didn't check the implementation: its the signature suggested list shuffling. Oh, well, it's fun reinventing the wheel!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your IEnumerable is a list you can use AddRange()

```
IEnumerable<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 };
((List<int>)list1).AddRange(list2);
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my code. It says the types aren't compatible since it's not all the same type, but two lists containing different sub-types of the same base. Also the whole point of interfaces is I have no idea the internal type from a .Net class. Two methods return `IEnumerable<X>` and `IEnumerable<Y>` that's all I know.