# Constructing an IEnumerable based on a collection of collections

Tags: c#, enums

Good afternoon,

I'm having a highly entertaining time trying to convince the 'yield' keyword to function in a way that I can understand, but unfortunately I'm not having much luck. Here's the scenario:

Based on the property of a user, I want to look up a set of RSS feed addresses and display the seven most recent articles from *all* of those feeds, not *each* of those feeds. To do so, I'm trying to build a collection of the five most recent articles from each feed, then take the 7 most recent from those. The (very dull) pseudo-code-type-process goes something like:

- Look up the the member
- Get the relevant property ( a group name) for the member
- Look up the addresses of the RSS feeds for that group
- For each address in the collection, get the five most recent articles and place them in another collection
- Take the seven most recent articles from that
  subsequent collection and display them.

I've done some research and been able to produce the following:

```
    public static class RSSHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> GetLatestArticlesFromFeeds(List<string> feedList, short articlesToTake)
    {
        foreach (string Feed in feedList)
        {
            yield return GetLatestArticlesFromFeed(Feed).OrderByDescending(o => o.PublishDate).Take(articlesToTake).First();
        }

        yield return null;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> GetLatestArticlesFromFeed(string feedURL)
    {
        // We're only accepting XML based feeds, so create an XML reader:
        SyndicationItem Result = new SyndicationItem();
        int SkipCount = 0;

        for (int Curr = 1; Curr <= 5; Curr++)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create(feedURL);
                SyndicationFeed Feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(Reader);
                Reader.Close();

                Result = Feed.Items.OrderByDescending(o => o.PublishDate).Skip(SkipCount).Take(1).Single();
                SkipCount++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Do nothing, else the Yield will fail.
            }

            yield return Result;
        }
    }
}
```

What seems to be happening is that I get five results (articlesToTake is 7, not 5), and occasionally either the whole SyndicationItem is null, or properties of it are null. I'm also convinced that this is a really, really poorly performing approach to tackling this problem, but I can't find much direction on using the yield keyword in this context.

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317546/how-can-you-create-a-collection-based-on-multiple-ienumerables) but it's not quite helping me understand anything.

Is what I'm trying to do achievable in this way, or do I just need to bite the bullet and use a couple of foreach loops?

Comment: " and occasionally either the whole SyndicationItem is null"  Well, you do `yield return null;`... what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @NPSF3000 It *should* be unreachable code, on the basis that there's always a string in FeedList. Granted, a check would be more appropriate, but I'll harden it when it's working.

Comment: So there's a string in feedlist, and once you process that it's going to go to the next statement which is to return null.  It's very reachable code.

Comment: @NPSF3000 - Thanks - it's been a *really* long day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morning,

Now that I don't feel like death warmed up, I've got it working! Thanks to @Rodrigo and @McKabue for their help in finding the eventual answer, and @NPSF3000 for pointing out my original stupidity!

I've settled on this as a result:

```
public static class RSSHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> GetLatestArticlesFromFeeds(List<string> feedList, short articlesToTake)
    {
        return GetLatestArticlesFromFeedsAsync(feedList, articlesToTake).Result;
    }

    private async static Task<IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>> GetLatestArticlesFromFeedsAsync(List<string> feedList, short articlesToTake)
    {
        List<Task<IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>>> TaskList = new List<Task<IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>>>();
        foreach (string Feed in feedList)
        {
            // Call and start a task to evaluate the RSS feeds
            Task<IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>> T = Task.FromResult(GetLatestArticlesFromFeed(Feed).Result);
            TaskList.Add(T);
        }

        var Results = await Task.WhenAll(TaskList);

        // Filter the not null results - on the balance of probabilities, we'll still get more than 7 results. 
        var ReturnList = Results.SelectMany(s => TaskList.Where(w => w.Result != null).SelectMany(z => z.Result).OrderByDescending(o => o.PublishDate)).Take(articlesToTake);
        return ReturnList;
    }

    private async static Task<IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>> GetLatestArticlesFromFeed(string feedURL)
    {
        // We're only accepting XML based feeds, so create an XML reader:
        try
        {
            XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create(feedURL);
            SyndicationFeed Feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(Reader);
            Reader.Close();

            return Feed.Items.OrderByDescending(o => o.PublishDate).Take(5);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

It took me a while to wrap my head around, as I was forgetting to define the result type of the task I was kicking off, but thankfully I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978057/why-does-task-whenall-return-void) this morning, which helped everything fall nicely into place.

I feel a bit cheeky answering my own question, but on balance I think this is a nice, tidy balance between the proposed answers and it certainly seems functional. I'll add some hardening and comments, and of course if anyone has feedback I'll receive it gratefully.

Thanks!
Ash

Answer (score 0):

Load your RSS feed in memory using `async` and `await`, then order them by date, and just [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) the first 7

Comment: I agree on the basis that it's a more performant solution, however I'm then left trying to compare five collections of results. The aim was to have one collection, so that I can then OrderByDescending on the one group of records. I suppose the missing bit from my question is how do I get the five collections into one IEnumerable to then allow for the ordering/taking of records.

Comment: 'I get the five collections into one IEnumerable'  SelectMany.

Answer (score 0):

Considering all you want to do in GetLatestArticlesFromFeed is to get the 5 latest items, wouldn't it be easier to only order the list once and then take the first 5 items? It would look like this (together with a SelectMany based approach to the first method)

```
public static class RSSHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> GetLatestArticlesFromFeeds(List<string> feedList, short articlesToTake)
    {
        return feedList.SelectMany(f => GetLatestArticlesFromFeed(f)).OrderByDescending(a => a.PublishDate).Take(articlesToTake);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> GetLatestArticlesFromFeed(string feedURL)
    {
        // We're only accepting XML based feeds, so create an XML reader:

        SyndicationFeed feed = null;

        try
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(feedURL))
            {
                 feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
            }

            return feed.Items.OrderByDescending(o => o.PublishDate).Take(5);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<SyndicationItem>();
        }          
    }
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, but it doesn't quite work, however I don't think it's your fault. One of the XML feeds that I'm using is, I suspect, encoded in a format other than expected, which causes an interesting exception to be thrown. As a result I'm getting some null reference exceptions, even when putting a save navigation operator in after the SelectMany predicate. I'll keep tinkering, but I think between this and Mckabue's answer I should be able to get pretty close.

Comment: Does this error occur while you're calling SyndicationFeed.Load? You can try surrounding it with a try..catch statement and, in case of exception, return a Enumerable.Empty<SyndicationItem>